# PHP identifying if decimal with multiple dots

Tags: php

In a simple calculator( which only display numbers if given ) I am taking the expressions in the form of string so I need to identify if the user is given correct input suppose if the user has given input on

> 12.34.56.788

then error should be given as it is invalid I tried identifying it by taking number of dots whose number if greater than 1 can give an error but if some expressions such as

> 1.2354 + 5.454 + 56.645

then it will give me an error is there any method or  function to identify if the given number is decimal with multiple dots ? thankyou

Comment: can you post your code here that what you did in your code?

Comment: presently I can't do it but can you say how to overcome with above expression with multiple decimal points as it give me an error

Comment: yes that is my point I shall suggest pseudo code but not whole code block right my friend

Comment: actually I have not written the entire code I am following this site http://andreinc.net/2010/10/05/converting-infix-to-rpn-shunting-yard-algorithm/converting infix to postfix and  making the operatons