# Evalute number using regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex to evalute numbers

> ^\d*(?:,\d+)*(?:.\d+)?

These are some numbers to check it

> 12345 -- correct
>
> .123 -- correct
>
> 23,456,789.123 --correct
>
> 123.456.7 -- wrong
>
> 1234. -- wrong
>
> 12345, -- wrong
>
> 123., -- wrong
>
> ,123 -- correct

but this last test case should be wrong. It should not be correct. Any help is accepted thank you

Comment: Your regex has some problems. I allows numbers like `,0.0` and `,0,0,0.0` or `0,0,0`

Comment: Did you find a solution for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48483522/php-identifying-if-decimal-with-multiple-dots?

Comment: Yes but it's not useful @Syscall

Comment: Thank you @ Federico Piazza for reporting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^(?!,|$)\d*(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?$
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sGq7IA/1/)**

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the line
- `(?!,|$)` - negative lookahead to make sure that the current position is not followed by either a `,` or end of the line
- `\d*` - matches 0+ occurrences of a digit
- `(?:,\d+)*` - matches 0+ occurrences of (a `,` followed by 1+ digits)
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - matches a `.` followed by 1+ occurrences of a digit. `?` at the end makes this sub-sequence optional
- `$` - asserts the end of the line

Answer (score 0):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/9qUzn8/1)

```
^(?!$)(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)?(?:\.\d+)?$
```

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(?!$)` Negative lookahead ensuring it's not also the end of the string (ensures at least one character exists)
- `(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)?` Optionally match either of the following options

  - `\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*`

    - `\d{1,3}` Match any digit one to three times
    - `(?:,\d{3})*` Match {a comma followed by 3 digits} any number of times
  - `\d+` Match one or more digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` Optionally match a decimal: dot `.` followed by one or more digits
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Answer (score 0):

Your regex `^\d*(?:,\d+)*(?:.\d+)?` matches the last case because it matches from the beginning of the string `^` a digit zero or more times `\d*`.
After that you match a comma followed by one or more digits. `(?:,\d+)*`.

This comma would match the comma at the beginning because of the zero or more digits before it.

In the last group `(?:.\d+)?` I think you should escape the dot `(?:\.\d+)?` or else it would match any character

You could update your regex to match an optional dot `\.?` at the start followed by one or more digits `\d+` and at the end add `$` to assert the end of the line.

[`^\.?\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/TwhzGx/1)

**Explanation**

```
^      # The beginning of the string
\.?    # Match an optional dot
\d+    # Match one or more digits
(?:    # A non capturing group
  ,\d+ # Match a comma and one or more digits
)*     # Close non capturing group and repeat zero or more times
(?:    # A non capturing group
  \.\d+ # Match a dot and one or more digits
)?     # Close optional group and make it optional
$      # The end of the string
```